# Cannot evaluate tensor using eval() error

Tags: tensorflow

I am following the code written in the tutorial [here](https://www.guru99.com/rnn-tutorial.html#2).
I have followed exactly each line, but I am receiving the following error.
Following is the error, followed by my code.

> ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session
>   is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit
>   session to `eval(session=sess)`

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_timesteps, n_inputs])

basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons)

outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
# #with tf.Session() as sess:
sess = tf.Session()

with sess.as_default():
    init.run()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    outputs_val = outputs.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch})

print(states.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have an active session for the print line. Bring it under the with sess.as_default() as shown below.

Use the following

```
> with sess.as_default():
>     init.run()
>     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
>     outputs_val = outputs.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch})    
>     print(states.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch}))
```